# How to determine a trespasser's intent from a Halachic Perspective?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, gezel-stealing, murder

How do we determine a trespasser's intent from a Halachic Perspective?

The Rambam [writes](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088876/jewish/Genevah-Chapter-Nine.htm):

> If it is clear to the house-owner that the thief who breaks in will not kill him and instead is only seeking financial gain, it is forbidden to kill the thief. If the house-owner kills him, the house-owner is considered to be a murderer.

And the Rema [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.425.1?lang=bi):

> One who "tunnels in order to steal" has this rule of pursuer applied to him, however if it is understood that his only intent is monetary gain, and that he would not kill the owner in a confrontation, then it is forbidden to kill him.

What is "clear" or "understood" enough?  Is the burden on the thief to be obviously non-threatening, or on the homeowner to judge leniently?  How is the homeowner to decide?

The above quote and my question grew out of the discussion here:
[Trespassers from a Halachic Perspective](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84992/trespassers-from-a-halachic-perspective/85021)

Comment: Rav Kuperman zt'l writes that one yom kippur ("kol nidrei") night he happened to be home, not at synagogue, and someone came into his house. The would-be thief had obviously picked a time when he figured no one would be home, which means he probably wasn't prepared to lethally silence anyone.

Comment: Check Pesachim 2b with Rashi and Tosafot https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.2b.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Comment: I feel like I tried commenting this earlier on this question, but I no longer see it here. Just a mareh makom: see Afikei Yam siman 40 ד"ה עוד.

Comment: I don't think there are blanket rules that can be made about this for the most part since intent is going to be situationally dependent. The one exception being if a person flees when they are caught out of fear then it becomes clear they don't have the intent to cause harm at that moment. Or one more example would be if the thief puts their hands up or gives another obvious sign of submission when caught.

Comment: Though no matter what your family's safety comes first and in a potentially dangerous situation decisions like this have to be made in a half of a second. You don't have time to analyze the situation like a sugya. Better to assume the person is dangerous unless they immediately submit themselves

Answer (score 0):

The Rambam in the same chapter bings that a father , just by being a that does not have the intent to kill you

> Therefore, a father who breaks into his son's home should not be killed.

The aruch hashulchan hoshen Mishpat [425.10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9104&st=&pgnum=518) (if I understand correctly) also bring this idea regarding a father
but he says if it is clear that the father (hates his son) and will kill his son then he is like any other person

(Related
[351.8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9104&st=&pgnum=370&hilite=) that while he can be killed if he damages the stolen property then he is exempt to pay (since someone you deserves to get killed does not need to pay other damages)

[358.(16-)18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9104&st=&pgnum=382&hilite=) brings other exceptions:.

1. If he left (the tunnel or the property).

   2. If he did not steel and is leaving (turned his back.
   3. Obviously If he is running away.
   4. If he was seen or became sorowneded by people or special witnesses while he was still inside
   5. If he is trasspasing to a place where usually there are no people there

Comment: have any rabbis, even in the midrashim, given an exception to this halacha?

Comment: @ninamag yes I just found it and am adding it

Comment: just out of curiosity, where can one find where a jewish father, via breaking-in, has killed his son? if there are such numerous cases, then can a halacha be over-ruled? can a halacha be ever over-ruled for any reason?

Comment: @ninamag I do not know where to find them (the killing was not via beaking in but after words when being cought). Halachas can be over-ruled if halachikly it is permitted, (halacha by definition is G-d's will , if his will is different in this case then it is different)

Comment: @ninamag a Rav (and every Jew should also) knows the reasons of the halochos if the reason is not applicable then the halacha is also)

Comment: See the sefer אפיקי ים in siman מ in the paragraph the begins, עוד היה נלע"ד.